# Executing R commands in Bash script?

Tags: linux, r, bash

From a bash script would I like to execute these R commands

```
install.packages('knitr', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("xlsx", dependencies="Depends")
install.packages("xtable")
```

One way would be to put them in a R file, then execute that, but I would prefer not to do that.

Can these commands be executed directly from a Bash script?

Comment: Try `Rscript -e "..."` (read `Rscript` man for details) or google for `littler`

Comment: Just use `#!/usr/bin/env Rscript` like you would use `#!/bin/bash` in an executable shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get -y install littler

echo 'install.packages("knitr", dependencies = TRUE, repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")' | r
```

`R -e` can also be used.